# Sinon anonymous stub passed as a parameter

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, redux, sinon

I am trying to test a function in a redux container but the issue is barely about redux or react. Basically the fetchData function I am trying to test, takes two functions as parameters and calls them.

What I was hoping to do was to have two anonymous stubs and pass them to the function this way:

```
var firstStub = sinon.stub().withArgs(mockResponse).returns('success');
var secondStub = sinon.stub().withArgs(mockResponse).returns('success');
AccountApp.fetchData({ firstStub , secondStub });
```

When this happens my function fetchData complains about the firstStub and secondStub not being a function. I know they are stub objects but if that is the case what is the correct way of managing this situation.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised to see the argument `{ firstStub , secondStub }` - i.e. you're passing an object `{ firstStub: firstStub, secondStub: secondStub }` - do you really want to do that?

Comment: Yeah I was a bit surprised on that one too, honestly I have no idea why anyone did that. Do you think it might be the source of the problem?

Comment: well seems that this is the problem now it is working fine, but don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the stubs as

```
AccountApp.fetchData({ firstStub , secondStub });
```

seems to be the culprit, because this means that you actually (after ES6 desugaring) invoke this:

```
AccountApp.fetchData({ firstStub: firstStub, secondStub: secondStub });
```

and this means that your fetchData() function would need to have an implementation like this:

```
function(args) {
   // ....
   args.firstStub(params);
   args.secondStub(params);
   // ...
};
```

I seriously doubt that your production code refers to those callbacks as "stubs". So you probably want to invoke the function like this:

```
AccountApp.fetchData(firstStub, secondStub);
```